# Change Bottom Sheet Content acc. to it's State

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottom-sheet

PROBLEM ::: I'm working in a bottom sheet where I have to show different content for different states of the bottom sheet i.e. for collapsed bottom sheet -> Content 1 and for the same bottom sheet in expanded form -> Content 2.

RESOURCES FOR THE PROBLEM ::: [PLEASE VISIT THIS GOOGLE DRIVE LINK FOR CODE FILES , CURRENT RESULT AND END RESULT](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1P6WsSu5EdrdJOn7OyECUaIVTpjDRaw26?usp=sharing)

WHAT I HAVE TRIED ::: I used if - else statement with scaffold state as a condition to see if the bottom sheet is collapsed or expanded and acc. to that I give the sheet content.

Anyhow, this approach is working but it seems like whenever I expand or collapse the bottom sheet , re-composition happens which is observable while previewing the app.